# C# Math 3D Movement x,y,z equation

Tags: c#, math

Hi guy's i got this math equation to movement the enemy x,y,z but i can't seem to replicate the result i want once am done with x,y i wanna create z movement also

So let's say i have a enemy with the movement speed of `1.5` his position is

```
Enemy Position: posX > 119.75013, posY > 12.1830482, posZ > 167.700226
```

I want to move him to

```
Enemy Final Position: posX > 119.41893, posY > 11.3724937, posZ > 162.9639
```

With these x,y,z result:

```
Enemy movement: posX > 119.645088, posY > 11.9535465, posZ > 166.198029
Enemy movement: posX > 119.539749, posY > 11.7193651, posZ > 164.691589
Enemy movement: posX > 119.479477, posY > 11.54633, posZ > 163.829742
```

But the function only prints

```
Enemy Movement: posX 119.182753804649, posY 10.7944934646909
```

Note i am not using Unity3D so i need a function that works with out unity3d..

Current function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double startX = 119.75013;
    double startY = 12.1830482;
    double startZ = 167.700226;

    double x = 119.41893;
    double y = 11.3724937;
    double z = 162.9639;

    double endX = x;
    double endY = y;
    double endZ = y;

    double speed = 1.5f;

    Console.WriteLine($"Enemy Position: posX {startX}, posY {startY}, posZ {startZ}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Enemy Final Position: posX {x}, posY {y}, posZ {z}\n");

    double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(endX - startX, 2) + Math.Pow(endY - startY, 2));
    double directionX = (endX - startX) / distance;
    double directionY = (endY - startY) / distance;


    double newlat = startX;
    double newLng = startY;


    while (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(newlat - startX, 2) + Math.Pow(newLng - startY, 2)) <= distance)
    {

        newlat += directionX * speed;
        newLng += directionY * speed;

        Console.WriteLine($"Enemy Movement: posX {newlat}, posY {newLng}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This question will be closed as off topic unless you can improve it. . Questions which ask "why isn't this code working" are off topic unless they contain more information.  Please go to [ask] and [help].

Comment: Okay edited ty.

Comment: There is no z movement in your code. So the z won't be affected

Comment: You must change the `newlat - startX` to `endX - newlat` Same for `newLng - startY` to `endY - newLng` You're subtracting the old value from the new value. But instead you still want the delta between te new position and the endpoint. You should use the Vector3 types/math. way easier..

Comment: I know z won't be effected i need to get the results of x,y right first to make the z .

Comment: If you don't want to use Unity i highly suggest you check out `System.Windows.Media.Media3D` namespace. Point3D and Vector3D can do most of the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, you use a speed of 1.5, that's your problem.

You compute

```
speed = 1.5
Δx = targetx - startx 
positionx = startx
while(distance(position,target) <= distance(start,target)){
    positionx += Δx * speed
}
```

At the first iteration, you already speed *past* the target, you are simply too fast to reach it.

If you want to have 3 positions in between start and target, you need 4 steps, therefore you should set speed to 0.25.

Which means, simply exchange `double speed = 1.5f;` with `double speed = 0.25f;`.

That said, I really **really** recommend that you make sure that you understand perfectly what your code does. That's why I wrote the part with the Δx. You should perfectly understand what Δx is and why it is applied as it is. If you use code without understanding it, and I suspect this, you have no chance to find a bug, should one occur. Or change the way things work. Also, you should really use classes. Your code would look much cleaner, especially if you'd use a class that represents a mathematical vector.

Comment: Don't really get how i can apply this to my code can you apply it so i understand?

Comment: @Premt You... exchange `double speed = 1.5f;` with `double speed = 0.25f;`. But *please*, do *not* use code that you don't understand!